# How do you parse a decimal string like .09?

Tags: c#-4.0

The following code is working fine with right format:

```
decimal.Parse(value.ToString());
```

A value like 2.34 works.

But, if the value is something like .765, it errors out.

How do I allow decimal.Parse to accept input like .765 and return the right value?

Comment: What kind of variable is value?

Comment: You're going to have to post more information - particularly your locale, what does `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString()` print? On an en-US locale, this will parse fine: `var str = ".765"; var dec = Decimal.Parse(str); Console.Out.WriteLine("dec = {0}", dec);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get no such error when parsing using:

```
Dim l = Decimal.Parse(".765")
```

I think your problem is happening somewhere else.

Comment: thank you. your are right. found out the reason and resolved it.